# To disable on click event on various html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a following scenario in which i have multiple td's in my tr, as shown below code:

```
<tr class="tbluplift">
  <td align="left">
     <a href="#">
       <asp:Label ID="lblStd" runat="server" Class="Quote"></asp:Label>
     </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In this, i want to disable a click on `td`, `a` and `label`, so to achieve this i have used the below code of jquery:

```
$('.tbluplift a').each(function () {
    $(this).css("cursor", "default");
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('hi');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

$('.tbluplift td').each(function () {
    $(this).css("cursor", "default");
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

$('.tbluplift span').each(function () {
    $(this).css("cursor", "default");
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

But, this code does not seems to work for me. As you may check i have used `console.log('hi')`, but i get nothing into my log. I guess the code is breaking in the `'click'` section. Its not even entering into it.

Does anyone has idea how can i achieve the functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but you are actually clicking the span/label, not the anchor, so preventing the click at that level stops it propagating to the anchor.

Best to use delegated event handlers instead:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q7mnvoqj/4/

```
$('.tbluplift').find('td,a,span').css("cursor", "default");

$('.tbluplift').on("click", "td,a,span", function (e) {
    console.log("click");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The delegated event handlers work by listening for the click to be bubbled up to an ancestor (in this case `.tbluplift`), so only one handler is attached. It *then* applies the jQuery filter and *then* runs the supplied function against any selected elements *that actually caused the event*.

Note, JSFiddle load the code inside a DOM ready handler (by default), so you may need to wrap your code like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.tbluplift').find('td,a,span').css("cursor", "default");

    $('.tbluplift').on("click", "td,a,span", function (e) {
        console.log("click");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: log is consoled, but its not preventing the default, i don't know why, the link is firing its click event

Comment: @HarshSharma: That is odd. `e.preventdefault()` is the only thing required. I assume the demo I provide works for you? (works for me).

Comment: Oh i think, i ignored some issue, in the span tag i have some text lets say "abc", so i noticed when i click on "abc" then the click event is fired however using the firebug tool i replaced the abc with blank value and the click event is not being fired, can you have any idea how to disable click on the text? Please let me know that

Comment: @HarshSharma: Can you update my JSFiddle with a better example of your HTML so I can provide a specific answer?

Comment: your Fiddle is of the same kind as of mine but i am having line height to my text

Comment: @HarshSharma: Can you provide a link to your fiddle so I know what you mean about the line height and removing span text etc?

Comment: @HarshSharma: It would help if you selected jQuery in the left hand menu of JSFiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5d4nx4dc/2/ Basically your code worked *but was not running* :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
// change cursor css for all elements inside tbluplift
$('.tbluplift').find('a, td,span').css("cursor", "default");

//bind click event for a, td and span inside tbluplift and return false   
$('.tbluplift').on("click","a,td,span",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/53bv6ez9/1/)**

Comment: your code is correct, but its not working for me can you help me please and guide me further.

Comment: ok, are you getting any console error? And now working means what exactly happening?

Comment: Please check the working demo link I added in the post, and put your code inside `$(function(){...});`

Comment: I have checked it and followed the way you told me to do, but still its clickable, like click event is fired.

Comment: click event will get fired as we have bind `click` event using jquery, but it will not do anything as we are returning false. If you don't want it clickable then you can make it disabled using `.attr('disabled',true)`

Comment: Oh i think, i ignored some issue, in the span tag i have some text lets say "abc", so i noticed when i click on "abc" then the click event is fired however using the firebug tool i replaced the abc with blank value and the click event is not being fired, can you have any idea how to disable click on the text? Please let me know that

Comment: what exactly you want to do by removing click event on text?

Comment: clicking on the text is firing my click event, because the text is having the line height i don't know how to stop propagate that

Comment: to avoid this you can add `e.stopPropagation()` after `e.preventDefault()`, this will solve your problem.

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar: `return false` from an event handler does the same as `e.stopPropagation()` *and* `e.preventDefault()`. You do not need both the `return false` and the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('td,a,label').click(function(){
  return false;
});
```

(or you can do it for the three separate elements)

Answer (score 0):

wrap the function in

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//your function
});
```

and make sure jquery is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me... you can check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wn8fy31e/1/

Anyway, you could write this code:

```
$('.tbluplift td a').css("cursor", "default");
$('.tbluplift td a').click(function (e) {
        console.log('hi');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Instead of:

```
$('.tbluplift a').each(function () {
    $(this).css("cursor", "default");
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('hi');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```